# Redirect issue in Yii framework

Tags: redirect, yii

In config/main.php I have this declared:
**'onBeginRequest' => array('Controller', 'reSetUser'),**

in protected/components/Controller.php I have this:

```
class Controller extends CController {
      public function reSetUser() {
          Yii::app()->request->redirect('/login/index');
      }
}
```

If i commented the reSetUser function, it works, it returns me the content of the view. On the other hand, if want to check smth and DO a REDIRECT, it gives me this:
[image]

in the firebug.

WHY? can someone help me ?

Comment: 302 is not an error, It is informing you that there is a redirect.

Comment: ok, but the result is the message: This page wasn't redirect properly. and the 302, appear multiple times

Comment: This will trigger for EVERY controller invocation. So everytime you call a controller action, the reSetUser() method will be invoked, redirecting you to login controller, which will call reSetUser() again (because it is in the extended controller. This will go on indefinitely. To get out of this, create your LoginController to extend CController, not Controller.